# assertion error using chai with mocha and webdriverio

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I am receiving this error

```
AssertionError: expected { state: 'pending' } to equal 'Platform Configurator'
```

I've installed `chai` , `mocha` through `npm`

It runs the test but doesn't pass assertion

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var should = require('chai').should()
var expect = require('chai').expect()
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

before(function() {
    browser=webdriverio.remote(options)
    return browser.init()

  });


describe('sauce labs page test', function() {
    it('should assert page title', function(done) {


           browser.url('https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/?_ga=1.5883444.608313.1428365147#/');
           browser.getTitle().should.equal('Platform Configurator');
           done();
    });

});
```

EDIT:

If I use this, using `setTimeout` it passes before the test completes or even before the page loads.

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var should = require('chai').should()
var expect = require('chai').expect()
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

before(function() {
    browser=webdriverio.remote(options)
    return browser.init()

  });


describe('sauce labs page test', function() {
    it('should assert page title', function() {


           browser.url('https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/platforms-configurator/?_ga=1.5883444.608313.1428365147#/');

    setTimeout(function () {
          browser.getTitle().should.equal('Platform Configurator');


    }, 10000)



    });

});
```

Comment: Is the content at saucelabs dynamic or static? If dynamic do you need a pause somewhere for content to propagate?

Comment: @zipzit I thought `done()` is doing that . I refered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143740/a-simple-webdriverio-mocha-test-doesnt-display-browser)

Comment: I'm no expert here. I'm learning Chai too. But I'm not seeing how that done command "knows" that all the JS code at saucelabs has finished propagating dynamic data. I'm just curious if you can artificially insert a delay and see if the results are different.

Comment: @zipzit  Edited above to include results with delay.

Comment: .getTitle is asynchronous. You are seeing a promise. Here is a similar answered question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663066/webdriver-io-elements-usage.  Or you can upgrade to V4, where everything is synchronous, http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/v4.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving getTitle

```
browser.getTitle().then(function(title){
  title.should.equal('Platform Configurator');
}
```

Comment: It worked but it is passing the test even before it loads the url fully. But that could be a different issue. May be it is genuinely able to fetch the title before url loads. Need to include more tests further down and see if browser waits for those tests.

Comment: Just an update that I included other tests and its passing all the tests before page loads. I am not sure at this point how to fix that.

Comment: @garajo how would you use the built-in expect commands which ever in the link https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect.html#tohaveurl